# Syntaxerror in jupyter on .iterrows

Tags: pandas, jupyter

I'm getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax for line 3 of the below, could anyone help?

```
up = word_stats.loc[word_stats['word'] ==  ['science']

for i,v in up.iterrows():

    k = 1000    
    xq = xb_word[[i],:]
    D, I = index_word.search(xq, k) # sanity check
    sample = word_stats.iloc[I[0]]
    sample = sample.reset_index(drop=True)
    sample["distance"] = D[0]
sample[['word', 'hot_uv', 'search_uv', 'distance']].set_index('word').sort_values('hot_uv', ascending=False).head(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
up = word_stats.loc[word_stats['word'] ==  ['science']**]**
```

may I ask where is your closing bracket?